# Most common way to refer to a baggage claim?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction

I’ve seen this alternately translated as “livraison des bagages,” “réclamation de bagages,” and “arrivée des bagages.” Which is the most common?

Answer (score 3):

My impression is the signs only say *bagages* in airports but if you need something specific, you might use any of these :

> [zone de] récupération des bagages.
>
> [zone de] retrait des bagages.
>
> [zone de] livraison des bagages.

*Réclamation* would be the desk where you complain about missing or damaged luggage and *arrivée*, when referring to an area, is more likely to be related to passengers while *arrivée des bagages* would rather tell the time of their arrival.